# Simple question: Reflections in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I am learning the reflections concepts in c#. I have a class like this

```
public class pdfClass
{
    public List<AttributeProperties> TopA { get; set; }
    public List<AttributeProperties> TopB { get; set; }
    public List<AttributeProperties> TopC { get; set; }

}
```

In another class I would like to extract the values from the list. I have stupid ways to do it like

```
public void ExtractValue (pdfClass incomingpdfClass, string type)
{
 switch (type)
 {
   case "TopA":
   foreach (var listitem in incomingPdfClass.TopA)
   {...} 
   breaks;
   case "TopB":
   foreach (var listitem in incomingPdfClass.TopB)
   {...} 
   breaks;
   ...
 }
}
```

The operations in the foreach loops are similar. How can I do this in a clear way by using reflections?

Comment: Why would you use reflection for this?

Comment: This question isn't clear enough.  The code you posted, specifically the second example, wouldn't compile (a switch statement cannot be in a class).  In the class ExtractValue, how are you getting references to the properties TopA, TopB, etc?  Does it inherit from pdfClass?  We need a better example to start with.

Comment: @Seen : Do you have an instance of pdfClass?

Comment: The ExtractValue code is not valid.  The switch code needs to be in a method.

Comment: You do not need to use reflection to do this. Just use the pdfClass instance.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, I tried to make it more clearer. If I don't use reflection, how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void ExtractValue(pdfClass incomingpdfClass, string type)
{
  PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(pdfClass).GetProperty("Top" + type);
  var yourList = pinfo.GetValue(incomingpdfClass);
  foreach (var listitem in yourList)
  { ... }
}
```

This is how you should do this using reflection. However, you should note that my code differs from yours in the fact that you are writing code that isn't clear nor would it compile. AS

```
public class ExtractValue (pdfClass incomingpdfClass, string type)
```

is non valid C# syntax if that is supposed to be a function as per my example this will work for you

Or if this is supposed to happen in the `Constructor` for the class it should look as follows

```
public class ExtractValue
{
   public ExtractValue(pdfClass incomingpdfClass, string type)
   {
     PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(pdfClass).GetProperty("Top" + type);
     var yourList = pinfo.GetValue(incomingpdfClass);
     foreach (var listitem in yourList)
     { ... }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I tried to make it clearer in my question statement.

Comment: @Seen your code still is not valid, but I am extending my example to help

Comment: Thank you very much....have not posted on stackoverflow for a longtime and made a lot of stupid mistakes.

Comment: @Seen that's what we're here for :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var property = this.GetType().GetProperty(type);
foreach (var item in (List<AttributeProperties>)property.GetValue(this, null))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have instance of pdfClass you do not need to use reflection for accessing lists.
I would suggest to decouple type from strategy itself by persisting such a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<string, Func<pdfClass, AttributeProperties, bool>>  strategy;
```

Once add relations like

```
 strategy.Add("TopA", (pdf, item) =>  
               { 
                 return pdf.TopA.IndexOf(item) >= 0; 
               });
```

and use like

```
string itemType = "TopA";
if (strategy.ContainsKey(itemType) )
{
  bool found = strategy[itemType](incommingPdfClass, listItem);
}
```

Comment: @Seen : shout here in case of any questions